# How can I compile native applications on my rooted phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, linux

I'm running Cyanogenmod 7 on my Nexus One, and I wanted to compile and run LAME on my phone. I've already downloaded the source package and have tried to `./configure` it, but I'm told that neither `cc` nor `gcc` exist on the phone. Is there a way to get `gcc` for Android? I'm simply looking to be able to compile a few native applications like LAME for use on my ARM device. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Is it necessary to compile *on* your phone, or would it be acceptable to compile *for* your phone? (in the second case, the executable is compiled elsewhere - on a PC perhaps - but compiled for the architecture of your phone) This could give you the basic idea: http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Compiling_for_Android

Comment: I can't find a C compiler than runs on ARM, nevermind specifically gcc for Android.  You're probably out of luck -- if gcc is ported it would probably take quite a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write, compile and distribute native code as an Android Application.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) for more info about the NDK.

If you want it done without the official framework and application packaging then you'll need to look into cross-compiling the application for the ARM architecture.

Comment: Err...that lets you use native code in your apps, not compile things on your phone, no?

Comment: I know that Al.  I never said that it was to compile it on the phone.

Comment: Yes, but that is what was specifically asked for (and another, duplicate question, was deleted).

Answer (score 5):

I can't understand why I have to pay $3 for C4droid as it's just GCC with an editor.

Use the new free CppDroid - C/C++ IDE on Android. It has a lot of included C/C++ examples and tutorials. [Blog link](http://cppdroid.blogspot.com), [Google Play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.cppdroid) (needs 190 MB).

Answer (score 3):

Compiling applications does not take considerable processing power in general. I did it on my 286 all the time. The OP wants gcc on his phone.

Look for [C4droid (C/C++ compiler)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc) in the Google Market.
Then install the [GCC plugin for C4droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.gcc4droid) from the market. (These do cost a couple of dollars).

From the market description:

> It's a plugin for c4droid, that allows it to compile C and C++ source code using GCC. It contains gcc 4.7 with Bionic (Android libc). Source code hadn't been modified, so you can compile it yourself, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The app [Terminal IDE](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside) has a built-in GCC ARM compiler for Android. You can install it, move it to another folder and then uninstall it. But make sure you have enough free memory (needs 150 MB).

Answer (score 1):

Android Applications are compiled in a PC and then installed on the phone. In order to compile an Application you will need a considerable amount of computational power and a compiler, in this case, a C compiler.

In other words, you need a Computer to compile the application.

You will need to download and install in your computer the Android SDK, the gcc compiler and other tools and then you will be able to compile the application for your phone.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, or if you wish to use 100% FOSS, you can install a native Linux installation on your device using apps such as [Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy), and simply `apt-get install gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Termux](https://termux.com/).Then pkg install clang.

Now you can compile and run c/c++ files.

Answer (score 0):

Termux and a linux rootfs, it's even better when you have a rooted phone. You can do whatever you want in there, install gcc, clang, jre, jdk etc... compmiling programs with gcc this is the best option and not very costly like I said if you phone is rooted you can have the rootfs image on your SD card and thus free space from internal memory